# Solve the equation for $x$: $mx + ce^{mx/c} = (c + pc + tm)/(1-p)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

I am trying to find the maximum values of this function:
$$f(x)=(1-e^{-mx\over c})(pt - (1-p)(t-x))$$

I took its derivative and set it equal to zero:
$$f'(x) = e^{-mx\over c}\left((1-p)\left(1 - {mx\over c}\right) + {tm\over c}\right) - (1-p) = 0$$

But after simplifying, I couldn't solve this equation for $x$:
$$mx + ce^{mx\over c} = c+{tm\over1-p}$$

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, the rhs of your last equation is not correct.

What I obtained is
$$m x+ c e^{\frac{m x}{c}}=c+\frac{m (2 p-1) t}{p-1}$$ Let $y=\frac{m x}{c}$  and $k=1+\frac{m (2 p-1) t}{c (p-1)}$ to have
$$y+e^y=k\implies y=k-W\left(e^k\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is am algebraic transcendental equation, so you're not going to get a closed form solution.

You can solve it using a Newton-Raphson iteration for given values of $m$, $c$, $p$, and $t$, and an initial guess for $x$.

To ensure that it's a maximum, you should evaluate the second derivative of $f(x)$ at the converged value of $x$ and establish that it is negative. Otherwise, you've found a minimum, and will need to start with a different initial guess to converge to a different root.